# Multiple Search Tab in PHP MySQLi

Tags: php, search, mysqli

I want to put multiple search option in PHP MySQLi. It has multiple forms for first name, last name, and email. It's already working, if I input, the First name only, the Last name only, email only, and first name and email. but when I'm entering the last name and email it errors. can you check my condition? thank you!

```
`<title>Results</title>
 <?php require 'header/headerResults.php'; ?>

 <?php
 $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');

 //search code
 if($_REQUEST ['submit']){
 $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
 $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lname']);
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);

// query for searching
$sele = "SELECT * FROM `examinee_detail` WHERE ";
$fn = "`firstname` LIKE '%$firstname%'";
$ln = "`lastname` LIKE '%$lastname%'";
$em = "`email` LIKE '%$email%'";
$both = "`lastname`,`email` LIKE `%$lastname%`,`%$email%`";

    // since there are three search bar, this are the conditions.
    if(empty($firstname)){
        $make = '<p>You must type a word to search!</ps>';
        }else{
            $make = "<div class = 'container mt-5'>
                    <div class = 'card mt-3'>
                        <div class = 'card-header'>
                            <h2>No results found!</h2>
                        </div>";
            $sele = $sele . $fn;}

    if(empty($lastname)){
        $make = '<p>You must type a word to search!</p>';
        }else{
            $make = "<div class = 'container mt-5'>
                    <div class = 'card mt-3'>
                        <div class = 'card-header'>
                            <h2>No results found!</h2>
                        </div>";


    if(!empty($firstname)){ $sele = $sele . " OR ";}

        $sele = $sele . $ln;
            }

    if(empty($email)){
        $make = '<p>You must type a word to search!</p>';
        }else{
            $make = "<div class = 'container mt-5'>
                    <div class = 'card mt-3'>
                        <div class = 'card-header'>
                            <h2>No results found!</h2>
                        </div>";
    if(!empty($firstname)){ $sele = $sele . " OR ";}
        $sele = $sele . $em;
        }
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sele);
                if($mak = mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){


    echo "<div class = 'container mt-5'>
                    <div class = 'card mt-3'>
                        <div class = 'card-header'>
                            <h2>Results</h2>
                        </div>
                            <div class = 'card-body' style = 'background-color: white'>
                                <table class = 'table table-bordered'>
                                    <tr>

                                        <th>First Name</th>
                                        <th>Last Name</th>
                                        <th>E-mail</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>"; 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){


    echo "<tr>
            <td>".$row["firstname"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["lastname"]."</td>
            <td>".$row["email"]."</td>
            <td><a href='ExamineeProfile.php?view=".$row['email']."' class='btn btn-primary'>View</a></td></tr>";}?>
 <div class = "container">
 <a href = "search.php" class = "btn btn-info">Search again</a>
 <a href = "examinees2.php" class = "btn btn-primary">Show full list</a><br><br>
 </div>

<?php
}else{
//echo'<h2> Search Result</h2>';

print ($make);
}
//mysqli_free_result($result);
//mysqli_close($conn);

}
?>
```

`

Comment: while mysqli_real_escape_string is better than nothing you should definitely consider switching to prepared statements, which are far harder to get potentially malicious input past.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it gives you an error is because your variable `$both` has an incorrect query.

You need to change it from this:

```
$both = "`lastname`,`email` LIKE `%$lastname%`,`%$email%`";
```

To this:

```
$both = "`lastname` LIKE '%$lastname%' AND `email` LIKE '%$email%'";
```

Comment: if I place $both in my code, where can I put it in my condition?

Comment: You would need to add something like this to your code to use $both variable

if(!empty($lastname) && !empty($email)){
        $make = "<div class = 'container mt-5'>
        <div class = 'card mt-3'>
        <div class = 'card-header'>
        <h2>No results found!</h2>
        </div>";
        $sele .= $both;
    }